# Run two kafka server separately on same machine

Tags: apache-kafka

I have two Kafka servers which are run in the same machine in Ubuntu. One Development Cluster consist of 1 ZK 1 Kafka Broker and 2 Workers, and Production Cluster consist of 3 ZK 3 Kafka Broker and planned 3-4 Workers.

Both are running, but Zookeeper in prod server are affected with the developer one, and when i see in my controller logs, it show some task  which run in dev and show that my prod kafka run in the same cluster as kafka dev. And also after several minutes, production server are down and only one broker are run. How to isolate and separate both of them so no can affect another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion 1: Use Docker Compose to completely isolate both stacks

Suggestion 2: Don't run more than one of any service on a single, physical server. Otherwise, should this one machine crash and fail, then you lose everything.